# Can't ping github.com and duckduckgo.com, able to resolve their DNS

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, ipv6, github

just finished setting up arch linux for the first time. The problem I was facing is originally is **slow download speed from github** when using

`git clone`

When I looked further I saw I couldn't

`ping github.com`

successfully the IP address gets resolved but I still can't ping it, these 2 issues **might** be related.
When I searched further it seemed that with this issue I can't

`ping duckduckgo.com`

as well, and this was due to some issue with **AAAA certificates** which I'm not familiar with

Any help is appreciated

```
PING github.com (20.207.73.82) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- github.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1021ms
```

IP Route

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.26 metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.26 metric 1002
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.26 metric 1002
```

Networkctl

```
IDX LINK   TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo     loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp7s0 ether    routable    unmanaged

2 links listed.
```

Comment: AAAA is a DNS record type, which has nothing to do with certificates. And neither has something do with pinging!

Comment: @MarcusMüller except AAAA are IPv6 address records, so there **might** be some IPv4 vs IPv6 setup issue. Can we have the output of `ip route` edited into the question? Does the OP think they are connected to an ISP which uses `carrier grade NAT` to work around a shortage of IPv4 addresses?

Comment: @icarus Edited it, I also think there's some IPv4 vs IPv6 setup issue

Comment: 2 default route going to the same next hop via the same device is unusual. The routing table shows no IPv6, which does simplify things a bit. The fact that DNS addresses are being resolved answers the question of if you have basic connectivity. Can you ping addresses like 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9 which are well known DNS servers?